# PayPal subscriptions button. Non-recurring

Tags: paypal

My understanding of the standard PayPal HTML code generated is that it will automatically ask
for a further payment in x months.
I wish to give my subscribers the opportunity to subscribe annually if they wish.At the end of this period they will need to renew their subscription (or not as the case maybe). I do not wish to go the Unsubscribe button route.
Can anyone please enlighten me with the amendment I need to make to the standard HTML script?

TIA

Comment: Cannot understand the question, please try to reformat the same.

Answer (score 0):

you will want to create a subscription button with the parameter modify=2 (2 will let only existing subscribers choose a plan). There's some documentation and sample code out there on the PayPal developer portal:

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADFA00WVU

HTML Sample: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADFK020OJ

You may also want to refer to the HTML variable reference under https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU

The process itself should be pretty straight forward.

The SRC value will determine if a subscription will recur (will be renewed) after the end of the billing period. Also bear in mind, that your website will probably have to send out notifications if you would like to have your subscribers update their subscription.

I hope this helps - otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to clarify your question a bit.

Regards,
Martin